# ATK4 & cron job, using of ds-addons/Scheduler

Tags: php, cron, atk4

I need cron job for my new application and found a nice add-on by DarkSide, but im having some difficulties using it.

The add-on is here: https://github.com/romaninsh/TemaOrig/tree/master/ds-addons/Scheduler

I have installed it till step 3, where windows scheduler reports "The windows cannot find the file specified".. but i guess i will try this tommorow.

What im really interested is some example of configuration (step4)

4a) Set scheduler global settings in "Config" tab.: How should i insert them, directly into database? So how do i insert: Important is, that you set "Heartbeat time" to exactly the same value (in minutes) what scheduled in your cron tab or Windows task scheduler.

Just a guess:

- name: Heartbeat time
- value: 5? Like every 5 minutes? Or do i put cron expression?
- description: ??

4b) Create Tasks.
I really do not know how to use this. What do i insert for Code, Class, Action?

Comment: up-voting. I wonder why somebody down-voted this without explanation ...

Comment: I wrote thanks in the end.. i guess Emilio Gort didn't like me being polite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually original source of ds-addons is here: https://github.com/DarkSide666/ds-addons and I'm author of this addons pack and particular add-on - Scheduler :)

**Questions and tips for you:**

- What is folder structure in your project folder? I'm of course especially interested where ds-addons folder is located.
- Which version of Windows are you using and do you have Administrator rights on that machine?
- Can you find file wscript.exe in your system hard-drive / Windows installation folder? In my WinXP it's located in c:\windows\system32 folder and as result is in PATH environmental variable and is accessible from anywhere. If that's not your case, then you have to provide full path to wscript.exe
- 4a is no more needed in latest version of add-on
- There is a sample Task class in readme in latest version of add-on
- In Windows scheduler you can set script to execute every minute or every 3-5 minutes not less. Otherwise you'll have big delays between scheduled time (in add-on) and actual execution time.

**Solution:**

Download latest add-on version from https://github.com/DarkSide666/ds-addons and check out changes in it's readme file.

Comment: Hey DarkSide :) With some testing and digging i found it out, afcourse its like you wrote in the new readme file (with example how to use it). I left the config table empty, don't really know what is for. But really nice addon, thank you very much!

Comment: At first config table was meant for some global add-on configuration, but it's still not used in any way by add-on. Maybe in future it'll be useful to save something there, so I left it where it is (and empty).

Comment: BTW, fork this addon and stay tuned. I have made some updates in it, but these are not released yet. I'll finish one project (where I use it) and then get back to add these changes in public version of add-on.

Comment: OK! :) 9 more to go... ;)